# Searching soft signs with normal character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am facing one issue in one of my Rails project.
My users database contain names with special character and i want them to be shown in search result while searching it with simple characters.
Example: Lets suppose i have a user whose name is "**Noël Nocciolo**"  (please notice soft sign on e) and i want that to be searched if i pass "**Noel Nocciolo**" as a parameter.

Can anyone tell me how to handle with these cases because no one knows how to provide input of "e with two dots".
And i am using postgres as my databse.

Regards,
Karan

Answer (score 2):

You can create separate field "indexed_name" for search and fill it only with ASCII characters.

Then you have to preprocess query string with `.gsub('ë', 'e')` (or any other non ASCII characters to its ASCII analog) and search with this processed query

and i believe there is more elegant way to convert any string to ascii analog i just gave you direction )

Comment: The problem here is my query string contains normal characters (Noel Nocciolo) but my database records contains non ASCII characters (Noël Nocciolo). The solution which you are proposing is vice-versa of the requirement.

Comment: it is not vice-versa but including situation if user find the way how to query 'ë'.. in simpler situation you can just directly search over indexed_name field, but you have to prepare it if you already have db with filled non ASCII name values

Answer (score 0):

`.parameterize` or `ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate` will probably be acceptable for your use case.

```
"àáâãäå".parameterize
 => "aaaaaa"
```

However, it won't handle ligatures such as `ﬃ`, so for that you'll need:

```
"àáâãÀﬃ".mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,'').to_s
 => "aaaaAffi"
```